# PHP Pagination of MySQL Query not incrementing/decrementing properly

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm having trouble with the follow PHP which paginates the results of a MySQL query.

When I go to webpagename.php with the first page of the results and click Previous, the browser changes to webpagename.php?page=-1 and shows the first page of results again.  If I click Previous again, it changes to webpagename.php?page=-2 and shows Page 1 of the results again, etc.

When I go to webpagename.php with the first page of the results and click Next, the browser changes to webpagename.php?page=1 and shows the first page of results again.  I then have to hit Next a second time to move to Page 2.

When I go to the last page of the results - Page 8 - and click Next, the browser changes to webpagename.php?page=9 and shows Page 1 of the results.  If I click Next again, it shows webpagename.php?page=10 and shows Page 1 of the results again, etc.

Expected Results:

When on Page 1 and a user hits Previous, I would like the code to do nothing/not decrement.  When on Page 8 - the last page of results, I would like the code to do nothing/not increment.  Of course, I would also expect that if you hit Next from Page 1 that it doesn't display Page 1 a second time but rather goes to Page 2.

Your exact changes to this code to make it work properly are very much appreciated.  Thank you for time.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());


// number of results to show per page
$per_page = 10;


// figure out the total pages in the database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uc_users LEFT JOIN ent_dancers ON uc_users.id = ent_dancers.id WHERE ent_dancers.DancerYesNo = '1' AND ent_dancers.DancerEnabledYesNo = '1' ORDER BY uc_users.display_name ASC");

$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);


// check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: webpagename.php?page=1)
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))

{
        $show_page = $_GET['page'];


        // make sure the $show_page value is valid
        if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)

        {
                $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;

                $end = $start + $per_page; 

        }
        else

        {
                // error - show first set of results

                $start = 0;

                $end = $per_page; 

        }               
}

else
{

        // if page isn't set, show first set of results
        $start = 0;

        $end = $per_page; 

}

// display pagination

// display data in table

    echo "<div class='dancerbio'>";
    echo "<div class='uts-1'>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)

{
        // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist

        if ($i == $total_results) { break; }


        // echo out the contents of each row into a table



        $rowid = mysql_result($result, $i, 'id'); 

        echo "<div class='uts-1-1'><a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename-details.php?userid=$rowid'>" . mysql_result($result, $i, 'display_name') . "</a></div>";


}

// close table>
    echo "<div class='ugen-1'></div>";
    echo "</div>";

$prev = $_GET['page'] - 1;

echo "<div style='clear:both;height:1px;overflow: hidden;'></div>";

echo "<br /><a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=" . $prev . "'>Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)

{
        echo "<a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=$i'>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

}

$next = $_GET['page'] + 1;

echo "&nbsp;<a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=" . $next . "'>Next</a>&nbsp;";
echo "</div>";


// pagination

?>
```

Comment: Just a side-note I highly recommend you begin implementing either a PDO or MySQLi approach to all your database transactions from now on. PHP's mysql_* functions have been officially deprecated and are pretty much considered an outdated strategy. In the next major release of PHP there will be no support for mysql_* functions. Google PDO vs MySQLi and go from there. It seems to be general concensus that PDO is better.

Comment: Some resources for your review: PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers - http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers
Why you should be using PHP's PDO for Database Access - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059
PDO vs MySQLi. Which should you use? http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
 if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))

 {
    $show_page = $_GET['page'];


    // make sure the $show_page value is valid
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)

    {
            $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;

            $end = $start + $per_page; 

    }
    else

    {
            // error - show first set of results

            $start = 0;

            $end = $per_page; 

    }               
  }
  else
  {

    // if page isn't set, show first set of results
    $start = 0;

    $end = $per_page; 

  }
```

by this:

```
   if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
   {
       $show_page = $_GET['page'];

       if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
       {
            $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;

            $end = $start + $per_page; 
       }
       elseif ($show_page > $total_pages)
       {
            $show_page=$total_pages;
            $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;

            $end = $start + $per_page; 

       }
       else {
            $show_page=1;
            $start = 0;

            $end = $per_page; 
       }
 }
 else {
    $show_page=1;
    $start = 0;

    $end = $per_page;
 }
```

then :

```
$prev=$show_page-1;
$next=$show_page+1;

if($show_page>1){//this way previsous won't appear if you are at page 1 already
   //show previous div
}

if($show_page<$total_pages){ //this way next won't appear unless you are not at the last page
   //show next div
}
```

Comment: CodeBird, this appears to be the same code that I submitted initially - the only difference being the addition of:

$prev=$show_page-1;
$next=$show_page+1;

if($show_page>1){//this way previsous won't appear if you are at page 1 already
   //show previous div
}

if($show_page<$total_pages){ //this way next won't appear unless you are not at the last page
   //show next div
}

This did not address the existing issue.  Webpage still functions as originally posted.

Comment: The difference is that we're not letting $show_page get bigger than total pages or less than 1, and we're hiding previous if there is no previous page, and hiding next if there is no next page. I added an elseif and some code in the top if statement

Comment: CodeBird, I did as I thought you had stated which is I put your code regarding $prev=$show_page-1;, etc. at the point you indicated after $end=$per_page;}.  It made no change to the existing issue.  If you can supply your answer using the originally posted code, I will then be able to understand your recommendation.

Comment: updated post to explain. check it out, hope it works.

Comment: CodeBird, thank you very much.  I found that I had $prev and $next defined later in the script.  I replaced those lines with your code and everything is now working using all of your code.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable $page set it equal to $_GET['page'].

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
else{
    $page = 1;
}
```

you need to put a condition before echoing previous link to check whether $_GET['page'] is set or not and is greater than 1.
Like this:

```
if($page!=($start+1)){
   $prev = $page - 1;
   echo "<div style='clear:both;height:1px;overflow: hidden;'></div>";
   echo "<br /><a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=" . $prev . "'>Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
```

Add another condition for next

```
if($page!=$total_pages)
{
    $next = $page+1
    echo "&nbsp;<a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=" . $next . "'>Next</a>&nbsp;";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

I hope your issue is solved.

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
{
    $show_page = $_GET['page'];

    // make sure the $show_page value is valid
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
    {
            $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;

            $end = $start + $per_page; 
    }
    else
    {
            // error - show first set of results

            $start = 0;
            $end = $per_page; 
            $show_page=1
    }               
 }

 else
 {

    // if page isn't set, show first set of results
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page; 
    $show_page=1;
}

// display pagination

// display data in table

echo "<div class='dancerbio'>";
echo "<div class='uts-1'>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
    // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist

    if ($i == $total_results) { break; }


    // echo out the contents of each row into a table



    $rowid = mysql_result($result, $i, 'id'); 

    echo "<div class='uts-1-1'><a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename-details.php?userid=$rowid'>" . mysql_result($result, $i, 'display_name') . "</a></div>";


 }

 // close table>
echo "<div class='ugen-1'></div>";
echo "</div>";

if($show_page!=($start+1)){
   $prev = $page - 1;
   echo "<div style='clear:both;height:1px;overflow: hidden;'></div>";
   echo "<br /><a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=" . $prev . "'>Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
        echo "<a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=$i'>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}

if($show_page!=$total_pages)
{
    $next = $page+1
    echo "&nbsp;<a class='bodytxt5' href='webpagename.php?page=" . $next . "'>Next</a>&nbsp;";
    echo "</div>";
}


// pagination

?>
```

Comment: asfandahmed1, could you possibly possibly make the recommended changes to the code posted?  I am not following where it is you want me to make these changes.